# How do I migrate google OpenID to OAuth? openid_id seems to be missing

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, openid

Since google has deprecated OpenID support, I figured I'd try to migrate, but boy is that an undertaking. I've gotten to the point where I can get user data from google, but I can't figure out how to get a user's OpenID identifier. The documentation says I can add openid.realm as a parameter when requesting the access code, and it should return an openid_id field. But it does not. My request looks as such:

```
$params = array(
    "response_type" => "code",
    "client_id" => $appdata['client_id'],
    "redirect_uri" => self::$REDIR,
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "state"=>$callback,
    "openid.realm"=>$openid->trustRoot
);
$request_to = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'. '?' .http_build_query($params);
header("Location: " . $request_to);
```

Returned fields:

```
["access_token","token_type","expires_in","id_token"]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with google?

Comment: Same here, did you manage to fix it?